# Batch File Function takes too much time to execute

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have written a function which gets the file name from a full path string.
But the subroutine I have written is taking too much time (about 4 secs) to execute. I am trying to understand why.

Here is batch file

```
@echo off
set fullPath=\\server\Dir1\Dir Number 2\Dir3\Dir4\abc.txt
echo %fullPath%
call:giveFileName "%fullPath%" finalName
echo After Function call fileName: %finalName% Good Job
goto:eof

:giveFileName
SETLOCAL
set fileName=%~nX1
::echo here is fileNmae %fileName%
(ENDLOCAL&set %~2=%fileName%
)
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that an attaempt is being made to LOCATE `\\server\Dir1\Dir Number 2\Dir3\Dir4\abc.txt`

Naturally, looking for that server is expensive.

If you remove the `\\server` it's reasonably slick.

Comment: +1, Good idea. I suspect the performance will likely be OK if the server actually exists, assuming the network performance is reasonable.

Comment: @peter-wright: Yes, if I replace server location with some local location (say c:\Dir1), it actually works fast. But I am still not able to understand why it should matter. Script is simply  declaring a string variable. And, it didn't instruct to look for that location.

Comment: Good, logical thinking. Only problem appears to be that it doesn't actually work in practice. It would probably come down to how the string is actually processed - that is, probably not as a string, but by passing it to some OS function such as INT 21H/60H. What the OS does with it from there is anyone's guess. It's actually a sensible approach - you don't have different implementations of filename-validation to be maintained in parallel. In this case, it slows things down. Certainly not the only poor decision made by whoever implemented the batch extensions.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this (*without any warranty!*):

```
@echo off
set fullPath=\\server\Dir1\Dir Number 2\Dir3\Dir4\abc.txt
echo %fullPath%
call:giveFileName "%fullPath%" finalName
echo After Function call fileName: %finalName% Good Job
goto:eof

:giveFileName
SETLOCAL
set "fileName=%~1"
FOR /f %%a IN ('cmd /c "ECHO %fileName:\=&echo(%"') DO set "fileName=%%a"
(ENDLOCAL&set "%~2=%fileName%"
)
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with the Peter Wright's idea, CMD is wasting time looking for remote `\\server`, which does not exist.

You can prevent CMD from doing that by prefixing the path with another folder. But this only works in your case where all you want is the file name and/or extension. Adding a prefix will obviously corrupt the result if you want the drive and/or path.

Also, your parentheses are not needed if you put your assignment on the same line as ENDLOCAL. But since all you are doing is setting filename and then immediately returning the value, you don't even need the intermediate value, and so you don't need SETLOCAL at all.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "fullPath=\\server\Dir1\Dir Number 2\Dir3\Dir4\abc.txt"
echo %fullPath%
call :giveFileName "%fullPath%" finalName
echo After Function call fileName: %finalName% Good Job
exit /b

:giveFileName
call :giveFileName2 "x\%~1" %2
exit /b

:giveFileName2
set "%~2=%~nX1"
exit /b
```

You can make the code even more efficient by using a FOR variable to get the name and extension. FOR variables use the same expansion modifiers as CALL arguments.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "fullPath=\\server\Dir1\Dir Number 2\Dir3\Dir4\abc.txt"
echo %fullPath%
call :giveFileName "%fullPath%" finalName
echo After Function call fileName: %finalName% Good Job
exit /b

:giveFileName
for %%F in ("x\%~1") do set "%2=%%~nxF"
```

If you don't mind repeating the FOR logic every time you need it, you can completely eliminate CALL.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "fullPath=\\server\Dir1\Dir Number 2\Dir3\Dir4\abc.txt"
echo %fullPath%
for %%F in ("x\%fullPath%") do set "finalName=%%~nxF"
echo After FOR assignment: %finalName% Good Job
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work faster in this case.

```
@echo off
set "fullPath=\\server\Dir1\Dir Number 2\Dir3\Dir4\abc.txt"
echo %fullPath%
call :giveFileName "%fullPath%" finalName
echo After Function call fileName: "%finalName%" Good Job
pause
goto :eof

:giveFileName
SETLOCAL
set "fileName=%~1"
set "fileName=%filename:~2%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%filename%") do set "filename=%%~nxa"
ENDLOCAL&set "%~2=%fileName%"
goto:eof
```

Comment: Sure, but you are assuming the argument always starts with \\. For example, your suggestion fails if the argument is simply `file.ext`. You really should verify the value starts with \\ before you remove the first character. I think it is much simpler to insert a prefix like x\.

Comment: @dbenham The variable does say `fullpath` so I can be forgiven for removing the first two characters willy nilly. :)  Adding a prefix is simpler though, you're right.